# Can anyone figure out his compound function

Tags: functions

I'm told this a very easy problem once you figure it out. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get past the first step.

The Identity Function I    Behaves Just Like 1.

That is,  f o I = f  And  I o g = g

It is also true that for the function K, K o K^-1 = I

Use this information to solve for f,    h = f o g

Comment: Is there enough information to provide an answer?

Comment: There should be. Like I said, this is supposed to be a relatively easy problem, I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: What kind of functions are you referring to in this question?

Comment: Wouldn't it be convenient if you could cancel out that $g$ in $h = f \circ g$?  How would you manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $g^{-1}$ exists.

$$h = f \circ g$$

$$h \circ g^{-1} = f \circ g \circ g^{-1}$$

$$f = h \circ g^{-1}$$